# Speed up cython code

Tags: python, c, performance, cython

I wrote a python code that manages a lot of data and thus it takes a lot of time. So, I found out Cython and I began to change my code.

Basically, all I did is to change functions' declarations (cdef type name(arguments with variable type) ), to declare cdef variables with its type,  and to declare cdef classes.
I'm writing all the `.pyx` with eclipse, and I'm compiling with the command `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and running it with eclipse.

My issue is that comparing python with cython speed, there isn't any difference.

I run the command `cython -a <file>` to generate a html file and there are a lot of yellow lines.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, I should include something else, and I don't know how to delete these yellow lines.

I just paste some code lines, that's the part that I'd like to speed up and because the code is very long.

---

## main.pyx

```
'''there are a lot of ndarray objects stored in a file and in this step I get each of them until there are no more items '''
cdef ReadWavePoints (WavePointManagement wavePointManagement, ColumnManagement columnManagement):
        cdef int runReadWavePoints

    wavePointManagement.OpenWavePointFileLoad(wavePointsFile)
    runReadWavePoints = 1

    while runReadWavePoints == 1:
        try:
            wavePointManagement.LoadWavePointFile()
            wavePointManagement.RoundCoordinates()
            wavePointManagement.SortWavePointList()
            GroupColumnsVoxels(wavePointManagement.GetWavePointList(), columnManagement)
        except:
            wavePointManagement.CloseWavePointFile()
            columnManagement.CloseWriteColumnFile()
            break

'''I check which points are in the same XYZ (voxel) and in the same XY (column)'''

cdef GroupColumnsVoxels (object wavePointList, ColumnManagement columnManagement):
    cdef int indexWavePointRef, indexWavePoint
    cdef int saved
    cdef double voxelValue
    cdef int sizeWavePointList
    
    sizeWavePointList = len(wavePointList)
    
    indexWavePointRef = 0

    while indexWavePointRef < sizeWavePointList - 1:
        saved = 0
        voxelValue = (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetValue()
        for indexWavePoint in xrange(indexWavePointRef + 1, len(wavePointList)):
            if (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetX() == (wavePointList[indexWavePoint]).GetX() and (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetY() == (wavePointList[indexWavePoint]).GetY():
                if (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetZ() == (wavePointList[indexWavePoint]).GetZ():
                    if voxelValue < (wavePointList[indexWavePoint]).GetValue():
                        voxelValue = (wavePointList[indexWavePoint]).GetValue()
                else:
                    saved = 1
                    CheckVoxel((wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetX(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetY(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetZ(), voxelValue)
                    indexWavePointRef = indexWavePoint
                    if indexWavePointRef == sizeWavePointList - 1:
                        CheckVoxel((wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetX(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetY(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetZ(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetValue())
                    break
            else:
                saved = 1
                CheckVoxel((wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetX(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetY(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetZ(), voxelValue)
                columnObject = columnInstance.Column((wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetX(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetY())
                columnManagement.AddColumn(columnObject)
                MaximumHeightColumn((wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetX(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetY(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetZ()) 
                indexWavePointRef = indexWavePoint
                break
        if saved == 0:
            CheckVoxel((wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetX(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetY(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetZ(), voxelValue)
            indexWavePointRef = indexWavePoint
    columnObject = columnInstance.Column((wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetX(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetY())
    columnManagement.AddColumn(columnObject)
    MaximumHeightColumn((wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetX(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetY(), (wavePointList[indexWavePointRef]).GetZ())



'''I check if the data stored in a voxel is lower than the new one; if its the case, I store it'''  

cdef CheckVoxel (double X, double Y, double Z, double newValue):
    cdef object bandVoxel, structvalCheckVoxel, out_str
    cdef tuple valueCheckVoxel
    
    bandVoxel = datasetVoxels.GetRasterBand(int(math.floor(Z/0.3))+1)
    structvalCheckVoxel = bandVoxel.ReadRaster(int(math.floor((X-Xmin)/0.25)), int(math.floor((Ymax-Y)/0.25)), 1, 1, buf_type=gdal.GDT_Float32)
    valueCheckVoxel = struct.unpack('f', structvalCheckVoxel)
    
    if newValue > valueCheckVoxel[0]:
        out_str = struct.pack('f', newValue)
        bandVoxel.WriteRaster(int(math.floor((X-Xmin)/0.25)), int(math.floor((Ymax-Y)/0.25)), 1, 1, out_str)

'''I check if this point has the highest Z and I store this information'''    
cdef MaximumHeightColumn(double X, double Y, double newZ):
        cdef object bandMetricMaximumHeightColumn, structvalMaximumHeightColumn, out_strMaximumHeightColumn
    cdef tuple valueMaximumHeightColumn

    bandMetricMaximumHeightColumn = datasetMetrics.GetRasterBand(10)
    structvalMaximumHeightColumn = bandMetricMaximumHeightColumn.ReadRaster(int(math.floor((X-Xmin)/0.25)), int(math.floor((Ymax-Y)/0.25)), 1, 1, buf_type=gdal.GDT_Float32)
    valueMaximumHeightColumn = struct.unpack('f', structvalMaximumHeightColumn)
    
    if newZ > round(valueMaximumHeightColumn[0], 1):
        out_strMaximumHeightColumn = struct.pack('f', newZ)
        bandMetricMaximumHeightColumn.WriteRaster(int(math.floor((X-Xmin)/0.25)), int(math.floor((Ymax-Y)/0.25)), 1, 1, out_strMaximumHeightColumn)
```

---

## WavePointManagement.pyx

```
'''this class serializes, rounds and sorts the points of each ndarray'''
import cPickle as pickle
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import math

cdef class WavePointManagement(object):
    '''
    This class manages all the points extracted from the waveform
    '''
    cdef object fileObject, wavePointList
    __slots__ = ('wavePointList', 'fileObject')

    def __cinit__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        
        self.fileObject = None
        self.wavePointList = np.array([])

    cdef object GetWavePointList(self):
        return self.wavePointList

    cdef void OpenWavePointFileLoad (self, object fileName):
        self.fileObject = file(fileName, 'rb')

    cdef void LoadWavePointFile (self):
        self.wavePointList = None
        self.wavePointList = pickle.load(self.fileObject)
        
    cdef void SortWavePointList (self):
        self.wavePointList = sorted(self.wavePointList, key=lambda k: (k.x, k.y, k.z))

    cdef void RoundCoordinates (self):
        cdef int indexPointObject, sizeWavePointList
        
        for pointObject in self.GetWavePointList():
            pointObject.SetX(round(math.floor(pointObject.GetX()/0.25)*0.25, 2))
            pointObject.SetY(round(math.ceil(pointObject.GetY()/0.25)*0.25, 2))
            pointObject.SetZ(round(math.floor(pointObject.GetZ()/0.3)*0.3, 1))

    cdef void CloseWavePointFile(self):
        self.fileObject.close()
```

---

## setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

import numpy

ext = Extension("main", ["main.pyx"], include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()])

setup (ext_modules=[ext], 
       cmdclass = {'build_ext' : build_ext}
       )
```

---

## test_cython.py

```
'''this is the file I run with eclipse after compiling'''
from main import main

main()
```

---

How could I speed up this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code jumps back and forth between using numpy arrays and lists. As such there is virtually no difference between the code that cython will produce.

The following code produces a python list, and the key function is a pure python function as well.

```
self.wavePointList = sorted(self.wavePointList, key=lambda k: (k.x, k.y, k.z))
```

You will want to use `ndarray.sort` (or `numpy.sort` if you don't want to sort inplace). To do this you will also need to change how your objects are stored in the array. That is, you will need to use a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). See [`numpy.sort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) for examples on how to sort structured arrays -- particularly the last two examples on the page.

Once you have your data stored in a numpy array then you need to tell cython about how the data is stored in the array. This includes providing type information and the dimensions of the array. [This page](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html) provides more information how to work efficiently with numpy arrays.

An example of show to create and sort structured arrays:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

DTYPE = [('name', 'S10'), ('height', np.float64), ('age', np.int32)]

cdef packed struct Person:
    char name[10]
    np.float64_t height
    np.int32_t age

ctypedef Person DTYPE_t

def create_array():
    values = [('Arthur', 1.8, 41), ('Lancelot', 1.9, 38),
              ('Galahad', 1.7, 38)]
    return np.array(values, dtype=DTYPE)

cpdef sort_by_age_then_height(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] arr):
    arr.sort(order=['age', 'height'])
```

Finally, you will need to convert your code from using python methods to using the standard c library methods for a further speed up. Below is an example using `RoundCoordinates`. ``cpdef` means the function is also exposed to python by a wrapper function.

```
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport floor, ceil, round

import numpy as np

DTYPE = [('x', np.float64), ('y', np.float64), ('z', np.float64)]

cdef packed struct Point3D:
    np.float64_t x, y, z

ctypedef Point3D DTYPE_t

# Caution should be used when turning the bounds check off as it can lead to undefined 
# behaviour if you use an invalid index.
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef RoundCoordinates_cy(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t] pointlist):
    cdef int i
    cdef DTYPE_t point
    for i in range(len(pointlist)): # this line is optimised into a c loop
        point = pointlist[i] # creates a copy of the point
        point.x = round(floor(point.x/0.25)*2.5) / 10
        point.y = round(ceil(point.y/0.25)*2.5) / 10
        point.z = round(floor(point.z/0.3)*3) / 10
        pointlist[i] = point # overwrites the old point data with the new data
```

Finally, before rewriting your entire code base, you should profile your code to see which functions the program spends most of its time and optimise those functions before bothering about optimising other functions.

Comment: I have an issue trying to do what you told me, and it's that I have a numpy array of objects, so I don't know how to sort this array using the example you sent me. A solution would be to do a new array having in each column the value of each attribute object, but it would take much time.                         What I also do is to serialize the numpy array using cPickle.dump and to load it using cPickle.load, I think that in this case there isn't any problem because I'm saving and loading a numpy array, is it? I'm going to do the other things you wrote me. Thank you very much

Comment: According to what you wrote me, I think I have to work with arrays with different columns instead of arrays of objects. Compiling C code I have some issues with cdef packed struct declarations, because in my case this is in a class, so I think I'm going to try to write all the code and function classes in a same file. I don't know if I'm right, but I'm going to try it

Comment: What's not clear for me is when I hace to declare a function with cpdef, cdef or just def, and if it returns something, do I have to include its type in the function declaration?

Comment: A `def` is a normal python function, usable in both  python and cython. A `cdef` is a C function written in python-esque syntax, but only available in cython. A `cpdef` is also a C function, however a helper function will be produced so that the function can be called from python. If you need more help then you should post a new question.

Comment: I've changed what you told me, but I don't really spead up the code. I've generated the yellow-shaded html file, and there are less yellow lines than before changing the code. How could I check which functions the program spends most of its time as you told me?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Changing the code as you told you me, it works (working just with one file and not with classes). But it's working with pytables instead of saving values into a tiff image how I could speed it up.